# Open Office - как удалить или переназначить диапазон

Tags: open-office

Выделяю к примеру **10 ячеек** с наименованиями, далее где отображается range типа **A1:A10**, в поле, пишу **List1**, Enter (Создается **List1** с этим диапазоном).

Далее где нибудь в другой вкладке я могу просто в меню **Validity** > **Cell range** > и вставить туда **List1**. Который станет **селектом** с моими выбранными наименованиями.

Трудность возникла только потом.. как его изменить или удалить или переназнать ? ничего из этих действий не получается сделать, они все эти листы есть - если кликнуть в поле где отображается номер выбранной ячейки.

Пробовал выделять заного с большим кол-вом наименований и применять тоже самое имя, ничего не выходит. Только нужно создавать новое имя, но дело в том что и старые удалить не знаю как ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

Выделить имя, удалить, выйти из окна обязательно после ОК

Comment: И редактировать там же можно.